# async_generator' object is not iterable

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I need to return a value in async function.
I tried to use synchronous form of return:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        return i
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

print(asyncio.run(main()))
```

output:

`0 [Finished in 204ms]`

But it just return value of the first loop, which is not expexted. So changed the code as below:

```
import asyncio

async def main():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

for _ in main():
    print(_)
```

output:

`TypeError: 'async_generator' object is not iterable`

by using async generator I am facing with this error. How can I return a value for every loop of async function?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use an `async for` which itself needs to be inside an `async` function:

```py
async def get_result():
    async for i in main():
        print(i)

asyncio.run(get_result())
```